# VPN Router drops connections

Tags: networking, router, vpn, connection

We are using a Netgear VPN Firewall Router FVS318v3..  We have a DSL connection here at the office, and my users complain of the connection dropping, or locking up on their end..  Latest firmware is installed, rebooting the router doesn't help, no other internet connectivity issues reported anywhere else (ie., no other internet connection problems here, or at their end, except when connecting to the VPN..)

Is there anything else I can check to pinpoint this problem?   TIA!!!

Comment: Are you using Network Address Translation? Is the router heavily loaded? Perhaps the NAT table is filling up?

Answer (score 1):

Some VPN servers / Bastard Operators From Hell configure the VPN session to disconnect forcing a re-signon entering username and password.

(In case you have wandered away from your laptop leaving their precious-most company lan at the tender mercies of the coffee shop waitress who just happens to also be an ueber-cracker)

Solution?

Open a terminal window.

Choose a deserving target

ping -i 30 target

This sends a packet every 30 seconds. VPN connection stays up!

Comment: Great, this works for me and an ASUS RT-N66U router.  I had "ping -i 30 -t target" to ping indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Traceroute
2. Load balancing tests
3. Wiring tests
4. Etc.

Do your standard network troubleshooting steps and you will be able to narrow the scope down.

Answer (score 0):

Caliban has the right troubleshooting steps.

You may also want to look at any patterns in your user's VPN client setups (Operating systems, VPN client settings). Vista VPN as been known to have some issues not present with XP, etc.